# How can I apply one of several classes to an element dependent on media query without duplicating code?

Tags: css, media-queries

So let's say I have an HTML element and it can have a "palette" class applied. The palette contains multiple color settings e.g. color, background-color, border-color etc. Sort of a color palette preset. Let's say there are 10 such palettes, so 10 classes. Applying this to the element is no problem, just putting the class name on the element.

But what I want to happen is, a DIFFERENT palette is activated at each responsive breakpoint. So e.g. on mobile the element may use palette4, on desktop it may use palette7 etc. There can up to 5 sizes ranges to respond to.

The problem is, this now seems to require me to duplicate all of the palette classes 5 times over, with unique suffixes. And then I have to put on the element something like palette4_mobile, palette7_desktop etc, in order to ONLY activate a given palette when in combination with a specific media query.

So basically then I end up with 50 palette classes instead of 10. This does work, but it's bloated. The css does compress *extremely* well due to major repetition, but it is 5x the size uncompressed. Granted, the duplication is encased inside each media query so this perhaps isolates it performance-wise.

Is there a way to make this same thing happen without having to duplicate the palette classes 5 times? I do not want to use any javascript. I also do not want to use "!important". I did consider that e.g if the element has classes like class="palette4_mobile, palette5_tablet, palette6_smalldesk" etc, that the later classes would override the earlier ones. But I couldn't see a way to disable the later classes within a specific media query without having to explicitly set all the values to something.. not really switching them off, just setting them to something else. Which results in even more longwinded code.

Any less repetitious way to deal with this scenario of 10 palettes, individually selectable in specific media queries?

Comment: I'd suggest you look into CSS Custom Properties...also known as CSS Variables.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see how that will help. It's not a problem of not being able to maintain the code or make changes to it, because it is actually generated by a server side script based on configuration settings. If I e.g. put various palette values into variables, I still have a) set up 10 palettes, b) have 50 actual classes because there's still no way to activate a specific one when a specific media query is in force.

Comment: The main issue is trying to get around the fact that for 5 unique classes that can be applied to an element based on the media query ranges, there are 10 possibilities for each one. And that means 50 possibilities.

Comment: @Paulie_D, using variables, how will it allow a specific class to activate on the element in a specific media query, without resulting still in 50 classes for all the possible combinations of element + media size? Just putting the color data into custom variables only allows the values to be changed more managably, it doesn't reduce the number of classes needed. Right?

Comment: Are there 10 classes with their own 5 color ranges? Do any of colors in the color ranges overlap? i.e. pallet 1 color range = blue => red => yellow and pallet 2 color range = orange => yellow => red.

Comment: @hungerstar there are 10 palette classes and each class contains numerous color settings. For example

.palette1{
   color:#123;background-color:#456;border-color:789; // etc
}
.palette2{
   color:#987;background-color:654;border-color:321; // etc
}

just a simplified version, there are in fact like 10-15 individual color settings per palette.

Then there are 5 responsive ranges needing 5 media queries. So a given element needs to be able to choose a unique palette per query, so it may look like:

<div class="pal1 pal3 pal7 pal4 pal9">content</div>

Comment: Are any of the color settings repeated in the 10 pallets? For the moment, I'm looking at reuse.

Comment: So e.g. when on a mobile device, palette4 is activated. When on a tablet device, palette6 is activated. etc.

I can do this by combining the palette with the media size into a single custom class name like 'palette6_onmobile'.... but this results in 50 classes.

Comment: @hungerstar there might be some repetitions, there might be none at all. it's possible that every single color attribute of every palette is totally unique.

Comment: each palette does have a setting for the same property, e.g. they all set color, they all set background-color, etc. That's the only guaranteed repetition.